# Is PHP's eval() function vulnerable to code injection when executing a string built from an array?

Tags: php, exploit, injection, code-review, code-execution

I'm trying to learn more about PHP eval() exploitation and I came across this scenario:

```
<?php

$test = array();
$test[0] = "command0 ";
$test[1] = $_GET["cmd1"];
$test[2] = "command2 ";
$test[3] = "command3 ";

$params = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($test); $i++) {
        $params .= "\$test[$i]";
}

echo $params;
echo "<br>";

$cmd = "echo \"" . $params . "\";";
echo $cmd;
echo "<br>";

eval($cmd);
?>
```

I've tried to inject several combinations of double-quotes and backslashes into the $_GET parameter but have had no luck breaking out of the $cmd string.

Beyond the XSS bug, is this code snippet vulnerable? Can this be abused for PHP code injection?

Comment: I think you have setup a bit of complexity for teaching yourself eval() exploitation. I did notice that when you define the strings in $test[x] for {x=0,2,3} there is a space afterwards but when you set $_GET["cmd1"] there is no string afterwards.

Comment: It was just a quick and dirty abstraction of some source code I was reviewing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not vulnerable to PHP code injection.

The string passed to `eval()` is simply not user-controlled. There is no path from the source `$_GET["cmd1"]` to the sink `eval()`:

- The argument to `eval()` is `$cmd`.
- `$cmd` is assembled from a fixed string and `$params`.
- `$params` is accumulated from a fixed string and `$i`.
- `$i` is an iteration variable that depends on the (fixed) length of the array `$text`.

That said, passing a generated array through eval is certainly not good style and you're obviously not sanitizing output which makes the code vulnerable to XSS.

Comment: Makes sense thank you, +1 for mentioning source to sink

Answer (score 1):

The code you are evaluating here is actually completely fixed, so PHP code injection is not possible here.

The code that gets `eval`ed is always:

```
echo "$test[0]$test[1]$test[2]$test[3]";
```

It references those variables as string data, which is safe (except against XSS).

Comment: Did you test this? e.g., `?cmd1=TEST` I get `command0 TESTcommand2 command3` but If I do `?cmd1=<?php TEST ?>` the output is `command0 command2 command3`.  I have tried  some PHP scripts, instead of `TEST` like `phpinfo();` it doesn't show me the output, but it doesn't show me the raw text from `?cmd1=`

Comment: @EricG That's because it's vulnerable to XSS and you don't see the pseudo-tag `<?php ...?>` printed. It becomes clearer if you inspect the source code.

Comment: Yep i was testing in the browser and just noticed now the browser escaped it inside html comments.